# Why is $1 =1 $? why is it so why cant be $1 =$ something else?

Tags: infinity, number-systems

It may sound stupid but why is $1=1$ or $n=n$ if thats the case does $1/0 = 1/0.$

Comment: Keep in mind that we use equality to capture the idea of "sameness". Something is the same as itself pretty much by the definition of "same". There's not much going on here that's more mysterious than the use of equality/sameness in normal language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because we define equals as an equivalence relation which needs to fulfill three properties

1. reflexive meaning $x\sim x$
2. symmetric $x\sim y \implies y\sim x$
3. transitive $x\sim y $ and $y\sim z$ imply $x\sim z$ where $\sim$ means it fulfills the relation.

Comment: In other words, that's what we want it to mean.

Comment: @Raskolnikov When equivalence is not an equivalence relation we surely did something wrong

Answer (score 2):

One of the defining properties for equality is that for any $x$ we have $x=x$. Therefore $1=1$ and $n=n$ by definition.

Now we *would* also have $1/0=1/0$ if $1/0$ existed. However, there's no such number as $1/0$, and for something that does not exist, obviously no equality can be defined.

Note that for equality we additionally demand that there's no other $y$ besides $x$ so that $y=x$. However this is in some sort a "soft" demand because we can always enforce it from an equivalence relation by simply considering equivalence classes. Also, to make that demand, you'll have to have an independent notion of what it means for two things to be "the same".

One example of the "soft" sameness is fractions: Formally, we define fractions as pairs of numbers with certain calculation rules (and a special notation of the pair to signify that we mean the fraction, i.e. those special rules for calculation). Now $\frac12$ and $\frac24$ are clearly different pairs, yet we consider them the same number. Technically, this means that our fractions are actually the *equivalence classes* of all $(a,b)$ under the equivalence relation $(a,b)\equiv(c,d)\Leftrightarrow ad=bc$.

Comment: maths showed non-Euclidean geometries can exist.. if you say something "exists", what you mean is that it doesn't introduce a logical contradiction given a particular set of rules. Is there any rule that defines 1/0

Comment: @xtechkid: $1/0$ would, by definition, be the solution to the equation $0x=1$. If such an $x$ existed, we would have $1 = 0x = (0+0)x = 0x + 0x = 1 + 1 = 2$, but we know $1\ne2$. Therefore $1/0$ cannot exist.

Comment: @xtechkid: There are other arithmetic systems (to which celtschk's analysis wouldn't apply). If you want to ask about other arithmetic systems, then you need to do so explicitly -- otherwise, people (rightfully!) assume you are using words and symbols to mean what those words and symbols usually mean.

Comment: @Hurkyl: In which arithmetic system does $0x=1$ have a solution?

Comment: @celtschk: I don't know (any commonly used ones). But you make a mistake in assuming that 1/0 would be defined to be a solution to $0x=1$.

Comment: @celtschk Wheel theory would be the main one. You modify the meaning of division so that it reduces to the normal one for the numbers you know and love, but can be extended to $1/0$ and the like.

Comment: That's interesting. Of course, looking at the Wikipedia page, it modifies quite a bit more than just the meaning of division; especially the distributive law is modified (indeed, it has quite a few rules which cover what normally would be covered by the distributive law).

Answer (score 1):

I think a non math answer would be that if $2 = 1$, then what is $1 + 1$? It isn't $2$ anymore (or is it? ), but we have $4 = 2$.

We are going to arrive at some inconsistencies.

EDIT: Actually to be more precise, we have to redefine '$+$' don't we? Should we go with your definition.

Answer (score 0):

Sticking to the title of your post, I think it is okay for you to define $1$ to be something else. But in that case, you have to deal with consequences of your definition.

Answer (score 0):

Take the number 0 then for axioms we have for all n exist -n then we know n-n=0 then n=n

Answer (score 0):

The symbol $1$ is reserved for neutral element of multiplication. The answer to the topic comes from uniqueness of multiplicative neutral element. Assume that $1$ and $n$ are neutral elements of multiplication. Then
\begin{eqnarray}
n = 1\cdot n = n\cdot 1 = 1 \ .
\end{eqnarray}
The first equation comes from the properties of $1$ and the third from the properties of $n$. That's why $1$ cannot be anything else.

The questions "Why is $1=1$?" and "Why it is so?" and "Why can't be $1=$ something else?" are separate and the first holds trivially. The second question refers to the first. Hence it is also trivial. The third question was answered above.

Also $n=n$ holds trivially. The equation $1/0=1/0$ is not defined according to standard definitions.